# STM32 16bits ADC oversampling and 2^n values noise and glitch problem

Tags: stm32, adc, noise, oversampling

I work on project using [STM32H753VIT6](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h753vi.html) and its internal ADC. When I increase the sample rate some strange glitch/artifact with values around 2^n begin to appear into my signal after 48kHz. and I know I don't understand why.

A microphone and opamp analog toolchain are connected to the internal ADC in differential mode. The STM32 do the acquisition and send data to PC application which record wav file. I permanently check the ADC input signal with oscilloscope and it's about good. (no glitch or artifact)

Glitch are not completely random in time domaine, there is no frequency so FFT not help that much but I will post anyway

Here is the signal (without no microphone excitation) at different sample rate with ADC configuration.

### @48kHz

All seem about good, random noise that I used to see
[image: Signal at 48kHz]
[image: ADC config for 48kHz]

### @96kHz

Glitch begin to appear, I can see the levels of those glitch samples create some "floor" or "stage" effect
[image: Signal at 96kHz]
[image: ADC config for 96kHz]

### @192kHz

Glitch are here to with the same "stair" affect
[image: Signal at 192kHz]
[image: ADC config for 192kHz]

### DISTRIBUTION / VALUES DENSITY

So I take a look on the distribution off the sample values on the different signal (all wav file are 10s)
[image: Distribution of the sample values]
We can see the good half gaussian curve for sample rate lower or equal than 48kHz, but greater than 48kHz, gaussian is destroy by abnormal density of value at 2^6, 2^7, 2^8, etc...

I don't understand what append, and how I can correct this to increase my sample rate and get a clean signal without those glitches at 96 or 192 kHz...

Can you help me ?

### EDIT 2021-05-26

Ok, I play with the oversampling ratio, when I stay lower than x16 signal is really good at any sample rate, equal or more than x16 glitch arrive. (I use 3.072MHz oversampling frequency)

Comment: Post a schematics, also. You could represent a FFT instead, your distribution density is not very helpful since the ADC is subject to aliasing with regard to sampling frequency, best seen with FFT. You could even attach a test signal of known frequency and amplitude.

Comment: From the datasheet "*The STM32H753xI devices embed three analog-to-digital converters, which resolution can be configured to 16, 14, 12, 10 or 8 bits.*". Do the number of bits decrease automatically with increase in sampling frequency ? See the section *6.3.20* also.

Comment: Can you try to digitize a signal, for example a sinewave? Its amplitude should be small, say about 0.02 on your scale, so the noise is still visible. This is to test if the noise adds to the signal, or if it's something else, like noise proportional to signal, or only occuring on certain amplitude levels but not others. Also test with a near full scale sine to see if the bits are in the right order. Also what is the output impedance of the circuit feeding the ADC?

Comment: Is this a multiplexed ADC ? It might have problems switching/settling in time.

Comment: How are you reading the ADC and synchronising with its sampling process? If you read the MSByte from one sample and the LSByte from another you'd expect to see a lot of 2^8 errors.